# Using absolute addressing inside a PE-file

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

The PE file in most cases uses relative virtual addressing (RVA). However, absolute addressing within a virtual address space is sometimes used. These addresses are then processed through a relocation table.
In what cases and why is absolute addressing used inside the virtual address space in a file?

Comment: How else would code refer to data stored in a PE image?

Comment: Can't this be done via RVA?

Comment: Which `mov` instruction would you propose?

Comment: Really. I checked the mov instruction for the variable, it uses absolute addressing. It turns out that the use of absolute or relative addressing is determined by the processor architecture? (ISA)

Comment: RVA doesn't stand for Relative Vritual Addressing. Just Relative Virtual Address.